# RTSP feed with ffmpeg and the Mac camera

Tags: terminal, camera, webcam, webserver

I have two Macs in my network. On the first one I want to capture the FaceTime camera via ffmpeg and make a RTSP feed available on the network, which I can watch on the second Mac.

Answer (score 4):

I successfully implemented something close to this (not true RTSP, but instead RTP streaming over UDP) with the following hardware and software:

- 2012 Macbook Pro, macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-mac) version 3.4.8
- [ffplay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html) version 4.3.2 (my executable was named `ffplay4`)

List the audio and video input devices with `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""`

On the 2012 MBP, the first video device (index `0`) is `FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)` and the first audio device (index `0`) is `Built-in Microphone`.

The video capture/sending and the video receipt/playback can be done on the same machine, or `ffmpeg` can send to a remote IP.  In this example, it is sending an MPEG transport stream over UDP to the loopback address `127.0.0.1:9988` but that could just as easily be the IP address and port of another Mac:

```bsh
ffmpeg \
  -f avfoundation \
  -pix_fmt yuyv422 \
  -video_size 320x240 \
  -framerate 15 \
  -i "0:0" -ac 2 \
  -vf format=yuyv422 \
  -vcodec libx264 -maxrate 2000k \
  -bufsize 2000k -acodec aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k \
  -f rtp_mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:9988
```

To receive and play the video:

```bsh
ffplay4 -i udp://@0.0.0.0:9988
```

It may take a few seconds to start up and there will be a few errors at first, but the video should begin playing in `ffplay4` within a couple seconds.

Bonus: this stream is also viewable with [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) (version 3.0.12).  `File`->`Open Network`->`URL` `rtp://@127.0.0.1:9988`.  Again, it will take a few seconds (5-10) to begin displaying the video.

Happy streaming.

Answer (score 3):

This is working in M1 Macbook Pro.

```
ffmpeg \
  -f avfoundation \
  -pix_fmt yuyv422 \
  -video_size 640x480 \
  -framerate 30 \
  -i "0:0" -ac 2 \
  -vf format=yuyv422 \
  -vcodec libx264 -maxrate 2000k \
  -bufsize 2000k -acodec aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k \
  -f rtp_mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:9988
```

After running this command you can use VLC media player to stream rtp://127.0.0.1:9988

Comment: Can you add some more details and explain your solution?